# Uso da função Knn no R

Tags: r, clusterização

Estou estudando clusters usando R.

Minha dúvida é se, para classificar novos entrantes com uma clusterização já realizada, a função **Knn** pode ser usada, quer seja para clusters hierárquicos ou  particionais.

Comment: Não entendo nada de R, mas que eu saiba Knn não serve para clusterização e sim para classificar/avaliar um entrante desconhecido.

Comment: Victor, obrigado pelo apoio. Eu entendi que essa função serve para classificar novos entrantes. Minha dúvida é se posso usá-la para clusters hierárquicos (ex: hclust()) bem como particionais (ex: kmeans).

Answer (score 3):

Depende de qual pacote você está utilizando o Knn, mas geralmente para avaliar o modelo você utiliza a função `predict(modelo, novo_dado)`.

Segue um exemplo utilizando o pacote `caret` que já escolhe os melhores parâmetros automaticamente:

```r
library(caret)

# fixar semente RNG para resultado reprodutível
set.seed(123)

# treinar modelo knn utilizando a coluna Species como saída
knn_model <- train(
  Species ~ .,
  data = iris,
  method = 'knn'
)

print("Resultado do treinamento:")
print(knn_model)

print("Predição da primeira linha:")
print(predict(knn_model, iris[1,]))
```

Saída:

```
[1] "Resultado do treinamento:"
k-Nearest Neighbors 

150 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  Accuracy   Kappa    
  5  0.9583142  0.9364989
  7  0.9573900  0.9350381
  9  0.9599157  0.9391095

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the
 largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 9.
[1] "Predição da primeira linha:"
[1] setosa
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pela ajuda. Vou testar aqui. Abraços.